# Qual a diferença entre `for x in y` e `Enumerable#each`?

Tags: ruby, loop, sintaxe

Podemos iterar um Array/lista em ruby de duas maneiras:

Utilizando a sintaxe `for x in y`:

```
> for x in [1,2,3] do
>     puts x
>   end
1
2
3
 => [1, 2, 3]
```

Utilizando o método `.each`

```
> [1,2,3].each do |x|
>     puts x
>   end
1
2
3
 => [1, 2, 3]
```

Qual a diferença entre elas, e quando devo usar um ou outro?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

São equivalentes.

`for a in b; code end` é um *syntax sugar* para `b.each {|a| code }`, com a diferença que a variável `a` não tem seu escopo limitado ao bloco. Uma prova simples para isso é o seguinte:

```
class A
  def each(&block)
    block.call(1)
    block.call(2)
    block.call(42)
  end
end

for x in A.new
  p x
end
# mostra 1, 2 e 42

p x   # mostra 42
      # a variável ainda está viva aqui, é a única diferença
```

Existia uma diferença de performance em que o `for` era menos eficiente que o `each`, mas isso é pouco significante a partir do *Ruby 2.0*.

Como referência, parte do [`compile.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/compile.c):

```c
// Ao encontrar um "for"
if (nd_type(node) == NODE_FOR) {
    COMPILE(ret, "iter caller (for)", node->nd_iter);

    // Crie um bloco para ele
    iseq->compile_data->current_block =
    NEW_CHILD_ISEQVAL(node->nd_body, make_name_for_block(iseq),
              ISEQ_TYPE_BLOCK, line);

    // Crie uma invocação ao método "each" passando o bloco
    ADD_SEND_R(ret, line, ID2SYM(idEach), INT2FIX(0),
           iseq->compile_data->current_block, INT2FIX(0));
}
```

Vale notar que em ruby é muito mais idiomático e preferível usar o `each` no lugar do `for`, mas isso é mais uma questão de estilo que prática.

Comment: `Nenhuma` e `a variável ainda está viva aqui, é a única diferença` se contradiz. :-)

Comment: Uma tentativa falha de *short answer*. Reformulei.