# Quando usar `for x in y` e quando usar `each`

Tags: ruby

[Na minha outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6184/qual-a-diferenca-entre-for-x-in-y-e-enumerableeach/6186#6186) eu descobri qual a diferença entre `for x in y` e o método `each`.

Agora, eu pergunto: Quando devo usar cada um deles? Poderia dar uns exemplos de casos em que se deve usar um e outros casos em que se deve usar o outro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que a outra pergunta já responde isto, não? A única diferença entre os dois é que no `for` a variável que é usada para fazer a iteração continua em escopo quando o `for` termina.

Internamente o `for` é igual ao `each`. Pessoalmente prefiro o `each` porque ele não deixa efeitos colaterais e porque parece mais "natural" dentro do estilo do Ruby. O `for` poderia ser preferido se houvesse alguma intenção de usar a variável depois do loop, para retornar o último elemento ou algo assim. Mas também pode-se argumentar que isto não ajuda na legibilidade. Se não há ganho de performance, deve-se preferir sempre o código mais legível e mais simples. Acredito que escolher entre um ou outro seja uma questão de estilo. Programadores Ruby costumam preferir `each`, mas programadores iniciantes que vêm de outras linguagens como JavaScript podem inicialmente achar mais fácil de entender o `for`.

Comment: A pergunta é um pouco diferente. Uma coisa é saber a diferença. Outra coisa é ter exemplos de uso. Eu entendo que o for mantém a variável fora do escopo, porém não consigo ver casos reais em que seja útil.

Comment: @fotanus Na verdade o `for` raramente é usado em ruby. Não me lembro de o ver sem ser em exemplos.